# White Gaps in Stacked Bar Flot Graph

Tags: jquery, graph, flot, stacked

I'm attempting to make a stacked bar chart using the jQuery charting plugin, Flot.

The data is coming in for both series in json format as: [{"label":"Uncategorized","data":[[1309374000000,"3448876"],[1309377600000,"3352757"]...

It seems like it's the same issue as what's happening here but no response has been posted.
http://groups.google.com/group/flot-graphs/browse_thread/thread/c6445ff7dce59ea0/e996979c40bc3f6b?show_docid=e996979c40bc3f6b

Anyone seen this error or know where I should be looking?

Anything past the most basic of examples for stacking appears to have severe issues.

I've tried reversing the series without any luck. All the data is sorted on the date and the dates correspond between the series.

http://rpbailey.net/flotError.PNG

edit: my flot options... two charts are being created, looking at the second (bottom) one.

```
                //get the date format
                strTimeFormat = "%y/%m/%d";
                if(strOb == 'Hour'){ strTimeFormat = "%y/%m/%d %H"; arrMinTick = [1, 'hour']; intBar = 1000000}
                if(strOb == 'Day'){ strTimeFormat = "%y/%m/%d"; arrMinTick = [1, 'day']; intBar =100000000}
                if(strOb == 'Month' | strOb == 'Quarter'){ strTimeFormat = "%y/%m"; arrMinTick = [1, 'month'];intBar = 3000000000}

                objOptions = {
                    colors:[ '#dddddd','#00ff00','#ffff00','#ff0000']
                    ,series:{points:{show:true},lines:{show:true},stack:0}
                    ,xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: strTimeFormat, minTickSize: arrMinTick }
                }           

                objOptions2 = {
                    series:{bars:{show:true, barWidth: intBar}, stack:-1000000}
                    ,xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: strTimeFormat }
                }   

                if(mode == 'percentage'){
                    objYaxes = {    yaxis:{
                         alignTicksWithAxis: 1
                        ,position: 'right'
                        ,tickFormatter: function(label, series){ return label +"%"; }
                    }};
                    //add on th yaxes options.
                    objOptions = jQuery.extend(objOptions, objYaxes);
                    objOptions2 = jQuery.extend(objOptions2, objYaxes);
                    console.log(objOptions);
                }

                 //top chart    
                jQuery.getJSON('includes/webRepFunctions.php', {chart:'risk',start:strStart,stop:strStop,ob:strOb,metric:mode}, function(data) {
                        jQuery.plot(jQuery("#flot1"),data,objOptions);                      
                    });

                 //bottom chart 
                jQuery.getJSON('includes/webRepFunctions.php', {chart:'cat',start:strStart,stop:strStop,ob:strOb,metric:mode}, function(data) {
                        jQuery.plot(jQuery("#flot2"),data,objOptions2);                     
                    });

                }
```

edit 2: some more sample data...

`[{"label":"Uncategorized","data":[[1309374000000,"3448876"],[1309377600000,"3352757"],[1309381200000,"2897092"],[1309384800000,"2747047"],[1309388400000,"2693610"],[1309392000000,"2511211"],......[1310097600000,"1404290"]],"yaxis":1},{"label":"Categorized","data":[[1309374000000,"1371941"],[1309377600000,"1273494"],[1309381200000,"1505119"],[1309384800000,"1463382"],[1309388400000,"1316429"],[1309392000000,"1201810"],......[1310097600000,"611780"]],"yaxis":1}]`

Comment: We need to see some source code for the options you have set for Flot, too.

Comment: Could we get a data sample? Stacked graphs can have some issues with certain series combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Do both of your series have the same amount of data points? I can't tell from this, as you've left some amount of data off. It seems like a bothersome question, but these graphs act strangely if you don't have the same amount of `[x,y]` pairs in each series. If it's undefined, use `null` in place of `[x,y]`. I'm thinking of what else may be the problem other than a very broken plugin, because I have plotted something similarly before and had a few issues, but I don't have access to that code anymore.

Try removing `objOptions2 = jQuery.extend(objOptions2, objYaxes);`
from your code. Again, this plugin isn't the best out there and has problems with some properties of Flot.

Also try removing `barWidth: intBar` from `objOptions2`.

Try removing them separately.

Beyond that, try placing the chart in question on a page all by itself, with no other HTML/CSS/Javascript, except what is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but had reference to both jquery.flot.stack.js and also to jquery.flot.stack.min.js

Once I removed the min js ref the white space gaps issue went away...

Comment: You are right, make sure you require jquery.float.stack once